# wget all linked files from a webpage

Tags: wget

First time poster! Im trying to get all of the .csv files linked on this website https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices however when i use the wget function it doesnt actually get the files (creates a prices file which opens as txt of the website).

```
wget -r --no-parent -e robots=off https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest there is a way to download all the **csv** files from the [link](https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices) that you have provided.

1. use the developer console to run a JavaScript to obtain all the href links in the site.

NB : since all the links in this particular site is of the csv file.we will be only getting the csv files link.

```js
var urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href);
```

2. now we have a js array with the links (urls) convert it to json for downloading as text file

```js
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
download(urls, 'json.txt', 'text/plain');
```

3. Format the text file so that we can perform a batch wget operaion on it.[image]
4. `wget -i json.txt` to download the csv files
   [image]

Comment: thanks for the reply! so do i try run step 1 and 2 in the chrome inspector console?

Comment: @SOK yes you need to run it in console

Comment: thanks. Ive tried and im getting an error: 

VM181:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: json_string is not defined

Comment: @SOK in your case its urls. i have edited the answer check above

Comment: Thanks. How did you format the txt file? I tried splitting text to columns in excel but there are too many columns

Comment: @SOK use a text editor like notepad++ to replace `,` with `\n` thus urls will be listed down in seperate line. then replace `"` with empty string to remove surrounding quotes.

Comment: Thanks again - got that done and now when i run the cmd i get 

Cannot write to 'bfprices_06042008.csv' (Bad file descriptor).
--2020-04-02 22:29:20--  https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/bfprices_07042008.csv
Connecting to promo.betfair.com (promo.betfair.com)|84.20.208.122|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
bfprices_07042008.csv: Permission denied

Comment: i don't have an issue when getting the files using wget. i have added an image in the answer. hope it helps